# VARCHAR2 should perhaps be DT_WSTR when working with SSIS against a Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, datatypes, ssis-2012

When using SSIS with Oracle database, it seems to always assume that a VARCHAR2 maps to a DT_STR.  However, if my Oracle encoding is set to AL32UTF8, I should be able to store any unicode character in a VARCHAR2, right?  **Is there any way to force SSIS to map an Oracle VARCHAR2 to a DT_WSTR?** Should there be?

I looked up a few other questions on this, but nothing seems to address it.

I have a data source that has many columns as DT_WSTR, and I want each to go into a VARCHAR2 column without having to convert every column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I need to be careful to specify my column length in CHAR. For example, Instead of VARCHAR2(255), I need to ensure it is VARCHAR2(255 CHAR).  If I do this, SSIS sees it as DT_WSTR.

Comment: Be aware that if you have existing scripts with `VARCHAR2(255)`, you can do an `ALTER SESSION` to set `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` to CHAR and then run them to get character rather than byte semantics.  That's easier than manually editing bunches of scripts.