# Oracle NVARCHAR2(4000) with AL32UTF8 possible?

Tags: oracle, datatypes

I thought, through reading items here and elsewhere, that if my Oracle database NLS_CHARACTERSET is set to AL32UTF8, I can have a column of type NVARCHAR2(4000), but when I try to create it, I get `SQL Error: ORA-00910: specified length too long for its datatype`.  **What is wrong with what I am trying?**  Are NVARCHAR2 columns always UTF16, unlike what I have read?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is AL32UTF8, any `VARCHAR2` column will support Unicode (via the UTF-8 encoding).  In 99.9% of cases, you'd never want to create an `NVARCHAR2` column.

The `NVARCHAR2` column, which uses the `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` which will almost always be AL16UTF16 is really only useful in a couple of cases.  The first, and by far most common, is when you have a legacy application whose `NLS_CHARACTERSET` doesn't support Unicode and cannot be migrated to Unicode but where you want to support Unicode data in a handful of columns.  That's not the case here.  The second would be when the database does support Unicode but you want to use the UTF-16 encoding for some reason such as the ability to store primarily Japanese and Chinese data using mostly 2 bytes per character in UTF-16 rather than 3 bytes per character in UTF-8.  But if you do that, you're still (barring 12.1 and the ability to have 32k `VARCHAR2` columns) limited to 4000 bytes (2000 characters in a UTF-16 column).  Hence the error when you try to define `NVARCHAR2(4000)` which would need at least 8000 bytes to store 4000 characters.

Comment: I need to use a NVARCHAR2 so that it matches up with the SSIS DT_WSTR data type, which I asked about here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114582/varchar2-should-perhaps-be-dt-wstr-when-working-with-ssis-against-a-oracle-datab . So you are saying that it just isn't possible to do a NVARCHAR2(4000)?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski If you need an `NVARCHAR2` column (which seems odd but I've not played with SSIS and Oracle and Unicode), then you'd use the `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET`.  Depending on the Oracle version, you may be able to set that to AL32UTF8 (but that would generally not be recommended).  Assuming your `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` is AL16UTF16, then you'd use the UTF-16 encoding for `NVARCHAR2` columns.  Assuming you are not using 12.1 or later with 32k columns enabled, then you're limited to 4000 bytes or 2000 UTF-16 characters.